Как автоматически передавать клиентам фотографии в сделке из множественного поля Фотоотчёты?
Пробовал создавать документ по шаблону. Но генератор документов видит только первую фотографию.
Хотел в бизнес-процессах загружать фотографии в отдельную папку на Диске и давать публичный доступ к ней. Но не вижу опции "Публичный URL". И не вижу опции загрузить файлы из переменной на Диск.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, любые решения, чтобы клиент автоматически получал фотографии из сделки после перехода на определённую стадию в воронке.
